# Cannot read property ‘0’ of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, upload, tinymce

Update: After doing some more debugging I found out that the `input` object has the files array, and the input element including the files array get initialized correctly, But when it executes the `input.onChange` function, the input object is suddenly undefined, therefor also the files array.

I have a tinyMCE editor in my app so that the web pages can be edited and videos and images can be uploaded. Unfortunately I lost all files of my backend yesterday. I’m almost back where I left off. And have now come to the point of uploading media. Even though the front end has not changed, TinyMCE media upload stopped working.

The culprit is `this.files[0]` which is undefined. Yesterday the exact same code ran without problems. Even though the typescript compiler also stated it was undefined, it still worked.

**TinyMCE init** located in my `nav` component:

```js
tinymceInit = {
    plugins: [
      'advlist autolink link image file lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
      'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
      'table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor responsivefilemanager code'
    ],
    toolbar1: 'undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify |' +
      ' bullist numlist outdent indent | styleselect',
    toolbar2: ' link unlink anchor | image media file | forecolor backcolor  | print preview code ',
    image_advtab: true ,
    image_title: true,
    images_reuse_filename: true,
    file_picker_types: 'image media',
    file_picker_callback: (cb, value, meta) => {
      const apiUrl = this.apiService.apiUrl;
      const templateId = this.currTemplateId;
      const input = document.createElement('input');
      input.setAttribute('type', 'file');

      input.onchange = () => {
        console.log('JSDJFSODNVONASDv');
        // @ts-ignore
        const file = this.files[0];
        const fileName = file.name.split('.')[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
          // @ts-ignore
          const blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
          // @ts-ignore
          const base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
          const blobInfo = blobCache.create(fileName, file, base64);

          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open('POST', apiUrl + '/templates/' + templateId + '/media');

          xhr.onload = () => {
            if (xhr.status !== 200) {
              alert('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
              return;
            }
            const json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            if (!json || typeof json.location !== 'string') {
              alert('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
              return;
            }
            cb(json.location, { title: file.name });
          };

          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());

          xhr.send(formData);

        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      };
      input.click();
    },
```

when choosing upload file and clicking open, the chrome console throws this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: just add the condition check `if( this.files && this.files.length > 0 ) {  //  do something 
 with this.files }` . the same  applies to other variables also

Comment: also replace the arrow function with normal JavaScript function for example  `input.onchange  = () => { }` cause if you use arrow function the value of `this` will change

Comment: @JoelJoseph That does nothing since it will never pass that statement. See my answer, files was seen as being a part of my component in stead of the input object. therefore the files will always be undefined if I were to only put that check there

Comment: I know ,  i have mentioned the same in my second comment

Answer (score 0):

The files[] is not getting initialized, that is the reason you are getting undefined. If the files[] is initialized from an API response maybe you should check the response. You were saying something happened to your back end. Trace the files[] variable in debug mode you will find the issue.

Comment: The files variable is from tinyMCE itself it has nothing to do with my backend yet. in the `reader.onload()`  is where my api gets used. but it the code doesn’t even get there. the `this.files` is supposed to be in an object tinymce creates.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: The `input.onChange` function should not be an anonymous/lambda function. Changing `input.onChanges = () => {` to `input.onChanges = function() {` resolved the issue.